# SAS proc import xlsm files

Tags: sas

I would like to do proc import for xlsm data.

```
proc import
    out = outdata
    datafile = "C:\User\Desktop\data.xlsm"  
    dbms = excelcs replace;
    sheet = "SheetA";
run;
```

The error message is:

```
ERROR: CLI error trying to establish connection: [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver]General error
       Unable to open registry key Temporary (volatile) Ace DSN for process 0x4058 Thread 0x3dc0
       DBC 0x2c1780c                                                            Excel'.
ERROR: Error in the LIBNAME statement
```

When i use dmbs=excel instead; i got following error msg:

```
ERROR: Connect: Class not registered
ERROR: Error in the LIBNAME statement.
```

Comment: Need more information for this.  Do you have ACCESS to PC FILES licensed?  Do you have a PC Files Server?  64 or 32 bit SAS?  64 or 32 bit Excel/Office?

Answer (score 0):

I think it should have something to do with PC file server under 64-bit system. A quick solution (which I usually use) is to first save your .xlsm file in .csv format and then do SAS import.